# How to find (union - intersection) of an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I want to Union minus Intersection of two images, A and B.

```py
U = ImageChops.logical_and(A, B)
I = ImageChops.logical_or(A, B)
```

result = U - I

here are the images:

A:

[image: image A]

B:

[image: image B]

Union:

[image: Union A B]

Intersection:

[image: Intersection A B]

The result I want should look something like this:

result:

[image: result image]

I am getting union and intersection by using ImageChops logical_and and logical_or respectively. However I am not able to get the result image U -I.

I will be applying the same formula (U - I) to many other images as well and I am not using any other external libraries.

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use XOR as this:

```
    X=ImageChops.logical_xor(U, I)
    X=ImageChops.invert(X)
    X.show()
```

[image]